# How do I package a vagrantfile so that it is used when 'vagrant init' is called on the box?

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I know this is a stupid question, I'm still struggling to grok vagrant.

I run vagrant on a windows host, and I'm building Linux guest VMs using VirtualBox. My guest VM is running, and now I want to package it.

The Vagrant documentation says "A common misconception is that the --vagrantfile option will package a Vagrantfile that is used when vagrant init is used with this box. This is not the case. Instead, a Vagrantfile is loaded and read as part of the Vagrant load process when the box is used. For more information, read about the Vagrantfile load order."

Got it. But that's what I want to do! When I run "vagrant package --output myboxname.box", my carefully-crafted Vagrant file does not appear to be in the package. I test the box as follows (in Windows, after copying the new box):

```
cd \some_new_dir
vagrant box add myboxname.box --name boxname
vagrant init boxname
```

The new Vagrantfile is the generic vagrant version, with none of my changes.

When I

```
vagrant up
```

The vm comes up fine, but (not surprisingly) none of Vagrantfile directives have happened.

I know I'm missing something basic -- can someone please help me out?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Packaging a base box with a custom Vagrantfile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14861604/packaging-a-base-box-with-a-custom-vagrantfile)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try copying the Vagrantfile from the directory you ran `vagrant package` in to the `\some_new_dir` directory.  Then, without running `vagrant init` (because this will overwrite the Vagrantfile with an empty file), run `vagrant up` to use the Vagrantfile.

Comment: I'll try this, I expect it to work. I had hoped there was a way to package the box so that it wasn't necessary to distribute a Vagrantfile alongside it.

Comment: This approach works (not surprisingly). Apparently there is no way to cause the box to carry its own Vagrantfile.

Comment: this does not even solve the problem that one want to package a Vagrantfile  within a box. I still don't get it. Documentation should say: It's not possible to package a Vagrantfile within a box